# Show that $f+g,c*f$ is admissible and Show that the positive and negative parts of $f$ are admissible.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

So I'm reading through C.H Edwards advanced calculus of several variables, and in the reading it says that it should be fairly obvious that exercises 1 and 2 should be obvious, and thus he doesn't prove them in the text. Perhaps Someone here could help me ?

**If $f$ and $g$ are admissible functions on $R^n$ and $c$ is in $R^n$, show that $f+g$ amd $cf$ are admissible.**

I realize that these are the conditions for a vector space, but im not sure where to go with that.

Also, the second question, which probably stems from the first:

**Show that the positive and negative parts of an admissible function are admissible.**

thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must check that $f+g$ is bounded, the support of $f+g$ is bounded, and $f+g$ is continuous except on a negligible set.

Given that $f$ and $g$ are admissible, we know they are both bounded and thus $|f+g| \leq |f| + |g| < \infty$.

If $A$ is the support of $f$ and $B$ is the support of $g$, then $\mbox{supp}(f+g) \subset A\cup B$ and since both $A$ and $B$ are bounded, so is $A \cup B$.

Finally, both $f$ and $g$ are continuous on a negligible set, so $f+g$ must be also.

The proof for $cf$ is pretty much the same.

The positive and negative parts of $f$ are even smaller in absolute value than $f$ and so are bounded. The supports are also smaller than the support of $f$ and so are bounded. Since $f$ is continuous on a negligible set, the positive and negative parts must be also since sign changes continuously or on the negligible set (this can be done more rigorously).

Comment: thanks for the answer... that makes sense... perhaps i need to read more about the terms in this chapter like bounded, bounded support and contented.

Comment: No problem. I encourage you to try to prove these statements above by trying to apply the definitions more closely. I kind of hand waved a bit.

Comment: I planned on looking at the second part more closely. I'm not the kind of person that wants everything handed to me. again thanks!